# Remove selector from angular2 component without create a component selector as a class or attribute

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to remove selector tag and want to render my component as element not as class or attribute actually my real problem is i have an ext js application where i have a ext combo and i need to create a component which can able to convert it to angular2 html for example

this is ext combo html

```
<ext:ComboBox runat="server" 
              ID="cmbColumn" 
              Width="280"
              FieldLabel="Update Data For " 
              LabelSeparator=" " 
              LabelWidth="100"
              IDMode="Static">
              <ng-content></ng-content>
    <Items>
        <ext:ListItem Value="POSSyncStatus" Text="POS Sync Status" />
        <ext:ListItem Value="IsDepartmentOpen" Text="Allow Open Sales In Department" />
        <ext:ListItem Value="IsFractionalQtyAllowedFlag" Text="Allow Partial Quantity Sales" />
        <ext:ListItem Value="IsLoyaltyRedeemEligibleFlag " Text="Allow Loyalty Redeem Sales" />
        <ext:ListItem Value="IsItemReturnableFlag" Text="Allow Item Returns" />
        <ext:ListItem Value="AllowFoodStampsFlag" Text="Allow Food Stamp Sales" />
        <ext:ListItem Value="AreSpecialDiscountsAllowedFlag" Text="Allow Special Discounts" />
        <ext:ListItem Value="PriceRequiredFlag" Text="Flexible Pricing For Items" />
        <ext:ListItem Value="SalesRestriction" Text="Sales Restriction" />
        <ext:ListItem Value="Tax" Text="Store Tax" />
        <ext:ListItem Value="DepartmentTypes" Text="Department Types" />
        <ext:ListItem Value="ActiveFlag" Text="Active" />
        <ext:ListItem Value="ProfitMargin" Text="Profit Margin" />
        <ext:ListItem Value="ProfitPercent" Text="Profit Percent" />
    </Items>
</ext:ComboBox>
```

and i want a to create some component that will help me to render this as

```
<select>
<option>A</option>
</select>
```

my idea is create component ext:combo and template is select 
but it also render ext:combo in html that is the problem and i thats why i can not write it as a class or attribute because i dont want to change my previous html

Comment: What does "want to render my component as element not as class" mean?

Comment: like <div ext:combo> i dont want to write this because in that way i need to change this many places and that is a very big application so which is in ext i just want to create component which can able to convert this ext html to <select> our angular2 html

Comment: Then don't write it :D I don't get what the problem is. Perhaps just me ...

Comment: the aim is just create a component which can convert ext html to select html

Comment: @ Günter Zöchbauer  are you able to get my problem ?

Comment: I think I get it now. Seems too broad for SO to me.

Comment: can you give me some idea how can i do this because it too urgent for me any help is really appreciated

Comment: You can try to create a component with a selector `selector: "ext:ComboBox"` and see if that works. You won't get the exact HTML output you want because it would introduce an additional wrapper element. You can also process the HTML yourself and create a component dynamically using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960. In case you want to know, in my opinion you should just not try to do that at all.

Comment: thanks for the answer but selector:"ext:ComboBox" does not help me because in the html it also render the <ext:ComboBox> which i dont want angular 1 have the way replace:true but i did not find any way in angular2

Comment: There is no `replace:true` in Angular2 and it was deprecated in Angular1 a long time ago.

Comment: so there is no way to achieve this in angular2

Comment: No, I don't think there is.

Comment: ok thanks for the help and yes then that is my bad luck if there is no way